# CakePHP: Fatal error: Call to a member function image()

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using the following Helper: http://pastebin.com/qBs2GvG4 in my CakePHP 2.0 app to show a gravatar for a user like so:

```
<?php $this->Gravatar->image($profile['User']['email'], array('default'=>'mm','size'=>48)); ?>
```

However it gives the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function image() on a non-object in /Users/cameron/Sites/social/app/View/Helper/GravatarHelper.php on line 97
```

Any ideas what the problem is? This worked in my 1.3 app so wondering if something has changed between 1.3 and 2.0 that causes this issue? Thanks

Comment: Simply $this->Gravatar or $this is null while you call the method image.

Comment: Hi, not understanding the problem as the code is being executed from the Helper as if I comment out the return on line 97 it will load the page with no error (no gravatar though) so it defo gets to that Helper file fine so I don't see how it's null...

Comment: I don't know how it can be null with a one-line code but PHP output that message in that case.

Comment: Any updates? Really confusing :(

Comment: Make sure the gravatar helper extends the HtmlHelper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helpers have slightly different dependencies in 2.0, especially if they require other helpers.I actually made the commits to fix this one in the [CakeDC utils plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/utils/).

You can find an updated version of that helper here: https://github.com/CakeDC/utils/blob/2.0/View/Helper/GravatarHelper.php

Comment: Yeah I realised their was an updated version of the Helper yesterday which has solved the issue. Can you shed more light on what the issues were as I'm confused about what changed that broke it. Thanks

Comment: @Cameron the issue was that 2.0 helpers expect the View (and consequently other helpers) to be passed to them in their constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the GravatarHelper has a dependency on the HtmlHelper. Is Html in your list of helpers in the controller?

Comment: Yes I have that in both the Helper and the global AppController

Comment: That's really weird. Line 97 says: `return $this->Html->image($imageUrl, $options);` which means that Html is not an object.

Looking at the GravatarHelper you linked, it is including the Html helper correctly, so I'm not sure why it's not getting initialized.